# Calcular ocorrências na string com sobreposição

Tags: python, string, python-3.x

gostaria de saber como fazer quantas combinações de substrings é possível dentro de uma string, ex:

```
   string = 'abcdcdc'
   sub_string = 'cdc'
```

o valor retornado que eu quero nesse caso, é 2, porque o código deverá ser capaz de verificar quantas combinações DA PALAVRA "cdc" poderão ser encontradas dentro da string.

A forma que eu tentei foi assim:

```
string = input().strip()
sub_string = input().strip()

idx = 0
count_p = 0
count = 0
for i in list(string):
    if i in sub_string[idx]:
        count += 1
        idx += 1
        if idx == 2:
            idx = 0
        elif count == 3:
            count = 0
            count_p += 1

    else:
        count = 0

print(count_p)
```

Já tentei de tudo mas sem sucesso,eu não tenho a menor ideia de como fazer isso, ficarei no aguardo, valeu galera!!!.

Comment: Pode colocar pelo menos uma das suas tentativas para podermos ver o que tentou fazer e ser mais fácil identificar sua dificuldade?

Comment: só não consigo formatar

Comment: Será melhor se você postá-lo direto na pergunta. Só copiar no editor, selecionar o código e pressionar o botão `{}`.

Comment: pronto!, agora ficou mais fácil verificar, foi mal pela demora, tive que refazer o código ;D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sua lógica, embora um pouco estranha, está quase que correta. O único problema é que, devido a sobreposição das ocorrências da substring na string, o seu código se perde nos contadores. Você implementou que o contador `count_p` seja incrementado apenas quando `count` é 3, porém como o último `c` da primeira ocorrência da substring também refere-se ao primeiro `c` da segunda ocorrência, o contador `count` chegará apenas a 2, mas não a 3, fazendo que o resultado seja apenas 1 e não 2, que seria o esperado.

Para resolver isso, ao invés de você simplesmente zerar o contador quando ele chega a 3, você verificar qual é o caractere atual e, se ele equivaler ao primeiro caractere da substring, atribuir o valor 1. Assim você estará contando duas vezes o mesmo caractere, o que configura a sobreposição das substrings.

```
string = 'abcdcdc'
sub_string = 'cdc'

idx = 0
count_p = 0
count = 0
for i in list(string):
    if i in sub_string[idx]:
        count += 1
        idx += 1
        if idx == 2:
            idx = 0
        elif count == 3:
            count = 0 if i != 'c' else 1
            count_p += 1

    else:
        count = 0


print(count_p)
```

<sup>Veja funcionando no [Ideone](https://ideone.com/5jAVXZ) | [Repl.it](https://repl.it/OICb/0)</sup>

### Ressalvas

1. Você não precisa converter a string para uma lista para percorrê-la com o `for`. No Python, o tipo string é iterável por natureza, então basta fazer: `for i in string`;
2. O seu código lê do usuário a string e a substring, porém a lógica está restrita ao exemplo que você deu, utilizando a string `'abcdcdc'` e substring `'cdc'`. Com valores diferentes, o programa provavelmente não funcionará;

### Alternativas

**Método `str.find`**

Outra forma de se resolver o problema é utilizar o método `find` da string. O método retorna a posição de início da ocorrência ou -1 caso não existir. É possível, também, definir o início de onde será considerado a string para evitar que conte duas vezes a mesma ocorrência. Um exemplo seria:

```
string = 'abcdcdc'
sub_string = 'cdc'

start = count = 0
while True:
    index = string.find(sub_string, start)
    if index >= 0:
        start = index + 1
        count += 1
    else:
        break

print(count)
```

<sup>Veja funcionando no [Ideone](https://ideone.com/uEaXeL) | [Repl.it](https://repl.it/OII4/0)</sup>

**Expressão regular**

Você pode também utilizar expressões regulares para obter todas as ocorrências da substring e contar quantas foram. Veja um exemplo:

```
import re

string = 'abcdcdc'
sub_string = 'cdc'

count = len(re.findall('(?=%s)' % sub_string, string))

print(count)
```

<sup>Veja funcionando no [Ideone](https://ideone.com/WVNJzO) | [Repl.it](https://repl.it/OIIo/0)</sup>

**Percorrer a string e comparar as substrings**

Você pode também percorrer todo a a string e verificar se a substring de mesmo tamanho é igual a substring que procura.

```
string = 'abcdcdc'
sub_string = 'cdc'

count = 0
for i in range(len(string)):
    if string[i:i+len(sub_string)] == sub_string:
        count += 1

print(count)
```

<sup>Veja funcionando no [Ideone](https://ideone.com/BnhI0W) | [Repl.it](https://repl.it/OIJy/0)</sup>

Comment: Cara, você é um MESTRE!!!, conseguiu tirar minhas dúvidas e mais um pouco ainda!, como vc deve ter percebido pelo meu código bem feio, eu sou iniciante em programação, ainda estou aprendendo como o fluxo da lógica funciona nos códigos e tbm como aplicar a lógica no código, por isso a estrutura do código está daquele jeito rsrsrsrsrsrs. Mas cara, parabéns pela resposta, vc MITOU !!!, não consigo enchergar uma resposta melhor do que a sua, valew cara !!! ;D